# Disable the body scroll, but keep it on individual div elements which are greater in height than the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched everywhere and have yet to get a solution. Okay heres the deal, I have a one page website which has several div elements underneath each other, sort of acting like individual pages I guess. What I want to achieve is to disable the scrolling of the actual web page all together, yet keeping the scroll of the active div in play if it goes below the web browser. To get to each other section of the page is simple done by using anchor links on the header.

Comment: What is the question? Can we see some sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but I think you want a div to be scrollable, but not the actual document. You can do this by absolutely positioning the div on the screen with a fixed height and set the `overflow` to `auto`. I've done this using the following CSS code:

```
#scrollable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}​
```

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/rgzBE/

Comment: You can read more about `overflow` on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 
`overflow-x:hidden;`

Comment: I think thats the answer to your problem, you need to play with overflow-x in the divs and the body, until you get what you want.
Maybe you could paste your divs and will be more direct our answers

Answer (score -1):

turns out its quite simple.
CSS

```
body{
 overflow:hidden;
}

#div_you_need_scrolling{
 overflow:auto;
}
```