# Disable horizontal scrolling by clicking the mouse wheel in the element with overflow-x:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I determine the possibility of horizontal scrolling by clicking the mouse wheel and disable it in the element with overflow-x:hidden (using JavaScript or jQuery)? Scrolling is impossible in Firefox but possible in IE, Chrome and Safari. Code example:

`<div style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">...</div>`

Screenshots:

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]
[image: IE]

Comment: If there is more content than there is space, you can either put a scrollbar or you can cut it off using `overflow:hidden`. How can you disable the scrollbar and also not have to hide the content?

Comment: Don't even worry about it. I'm not even sure it's possible and if it is it would just piss me off someone deciding to screw with mouse functionality.

Comment: Look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058202/disable-the-body-scroll-but-keep-it-on-individual-div-elements-which-are-greate/13058634#13058634 I have disabled scroll on body element, just change script to fit your needs

Comment: I clarified the question and added screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly possible, but not best practise (I presume you have a really good reason for wanting to do it, though):

```
$('#yourDivId').on('scroll', function(){
    $('#container').scrollLeft(0);
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/q5CTS/3/ for a working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can disble it with jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.parent').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
   return false;
}); 

});
```

The class parant is parent div.